# MacFUSE does not appear to be installed

Tags: macos, osx-lion, ntfs, macfuse

After installing MacFUSE and opening system Preferences -> MacFuse
it looks like that it is not compatible with Mac lion and says:

> MacFUSE does not appear to be installed

Any solution to that?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I solved this issue by downloading and installing 
[macfuse-core-10.5-2.1.9.dmg](http://www.tuxera.com/mac/macfuse-core-10.5-2.1.9.dmg)

 I found the answer on [MacFUSE OSX 10.7 - Seems to be not installed](http://macfuse.975588.n3.nabble.com/OSX-10-7-Seems-to-be-not-installed-td3147712.html)

Answer (score 1):

The Google Code [Home Page](http://code.google.com/p/macfuse/) for MacFUSE says it is no longer being maintained and specifically mention Lion:

> This project is no longer being maintained. We cannot currently help with any lion (or any large feline) related bugs or issues. [The MacFuse google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/macfuse) is a decent resource for finding forks/replacement projects.